# LINQ deferred execution when updating a property

Tags: c#, linq, deferred-execution

I have the following C# code:

```
#nullable enable

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var userNames = new List<string>{"Jon Doe", "Jane Doe"};
        var persons = userNames.Select(x => new Person{ Name = x });
        
        foreach (var person in persons)
        {
            person.FamilyName = person.Name.Split(' ').Last();
        }

        var familyNameList = persons.Select(x => x.FamilyName).ToList();
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", familyNameList));
    }

    private class Person
    {
        public required string Name { get; init; }

        public string? FamilyName { get; set; }
    }
}

#nullable disable
```

The console outputs:

```
 ,
```

And upon inspecting the `familyNameList` list, I find that it only contains `null` values.

I understand that deferred execution is in play, but why is the `FamilyName` not set in the `foreach` loop?

And if the `Person` is not instantiated before `.ToList()` is called, then why is there no `NullReferenceException` thrown when trying to set the `FamilyName` property?

Link to .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/VMKXEw

Comment: Each time you loop over `persons`, it will create an entirely new set of `Person` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short - materialize the enumerable:

```
var persons = userNames.Select(x => new Person{ Name = x }).ToList();
```

> I understand that deferred execution is in play, but why is the FamilyName not set in the foreach loop?

It is set but the results are effectively discarded. I.e. the following:

```
var familyNameList = persons.Select(x => x.FamilyName).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", familyNameList));
```

Will iterate a completely new collection of freshly created persons. LINQ is lazy and the actual execution is [deferred](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/deferred-execution-example) until  one of the materializable operations (`Count`, `foreach`, `ToList`, `First`, etc.). And the whole enumerable will be enumerated for every such operation (with the exception of some [optimizations like for `Count`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Count.cs,11) when the passed `IEnumerable<T>` is actually materialized and has count).

Just add a side-effect to the original enumerable:

```
var persons = userNames.Select(x =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    return new Person{Name = x};
});
```

And the output will speak for itself.